# Android - what is gradle task connectedCheck used for

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run the following command I get a description of `connectedCheck` but I'm still not sure what it's used for. Could anyone give me a real world example?

```
./gradlew tasks prints

...
Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
connectedCheck - Runs all device checks on currently connected devices.
connectedInstrumentTest - Installs and runs the tests for Build 'Debug' on connected devices.
deviceCheck - Runs all device checks using Device Providers and Test Servers.
...
```

Comment: This task runs your UI tests (e.g. with Espresso) on devices and emulators.

Comment: so i would not run "gradlew test" for instrumentation tests ? i'd run "gradlew connectedCheck"  ... is that right ?

Comment: That is correct. With 'test' you'll run JUnit tests.

Comment: your right, thats how to run instrumentation tests. if you want to post a offical answer you can, thanks.

Comment: It's too late. There is also a more detailed answer ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Command `./gradlew connectedCheck` executes instrumentation tests located in `src/androidTests/` directory on connected Android device or emulator. Such tests can have dependencies to Android API. These tests can be simple assertions or UI tests with Espresso framework or something similar. Yesterday I wrote post about Android automated tests including more detailed description of them. You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31975806/1150795).

Comment: I don't think you can call tests on Android devices Unit Tests.

Comment: I don't understand your reply. Statement in my answer is true, I tested it and it works.

Comment: `executes unit tests located in src/androidTests/`. That's not the folder for unit tests. These are functional tests.

Comment: It depends on organisation of your project and its infrastructure. Probably you're right as well and we can put functional tests there. Nevertheless, if you want to execute unit tests which have dependencies to Android SDK, you should put them to `androidTests` directory or use different approach - e.g. with Robolectric. Unit tests located in `test` directory cannot have dependencies to Android SDK in default configuration.

Comment: Yes. It was just a comment on your correct answer :)